# gulp useref not working with multiple html files

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, gulp, gulp-useref

I have 5 HTML files in my project and every has a useref block in the bottom like this:

```
<!-- build:js static/js/main.js -->
<script src="static/js/plugins.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

Common JS file in all 5 files are plugins.js . I need that JS file in every HTML file and its repeating in all my files. 
My second HTML file has this block (again plugins.js is there) :

```
<!-- build:js static/js/main.js -->
<script src="static/js/jquery.barrating.min.js"></script>
<script src="static/js/plugins.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

And my fifth HTML file has this block:

```
<!-- build:js static/js/main.js -->
<script src="static/js/jquery.matchHeight-min.js"></script>
<script src="static/js/jquery.barrating.min.js"></script>
<script src="static/js/plugins.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

So in every file im using plugins.js and in some files i use some other libraries. But when i run task this three files are not concatenated into main.js. Only thing in main.js is content from plugins.js . Other libraries are not included into main.js.
Why is that so? Can i even use this plugin like that?

My gulp task:

```
gulp.task('compress:js:html', ['clear:dist'], function () {
    return gulp.src('./*.html')
        .pipe(useref())
        .pipe(htmlmin({collapseWhitespace: true}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'))
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All your HTML files specify the same location for the concatenated file (`static/js/main.js`), but they all specify different source files that should be concatenated. Depending on the order in which your HTML files are processed you end up with a different `static/js/main.js`. In your case the one from your first example.

You have two options:

1. For each HTML file specify a different location for the concatenated file:

   HTML File 1:

   ```
   <!-- build:js static/js/main1.js -->
   <script src="static/js/plugins.js"></script>
   <!-- endbuild -->
   ```

   HTML File 2:

   ```
   <!-- build:js static/js/main2.js -->
   <script src="static/js/jquery.barrating.min.js"></script>
   <script src="static/js/plugins.js"></script>
   <!-- endbuild -->
   ```

   HTML File 3:

   ```
   <!-- build:js static/js/main3.js -->
   <script src="static/js/jquery.matchHeight-min.js"></script>
   <script src="static/js/jquery.barrating.min.js"></script>
   <script src="static/js/plugins.js"></script>
   <!-- endbuild -->
   ```

   This will reduce the number of requests a browser has to make for each page, but it doesn't leverage browser caching.
2. Refer to *all* JS files in each HTML file, whether you need the JS file for that specific page or not. That means you have the following in all three of your HTML files:

   ```
   <!-- build:js static/js/main.js -->
   <script src="static/js/jquery.matchHeight-min.js"></script>
   <script src="static/js/jquery.barrating.min.js"></script>
   <script src="static/js/plugins.js"></script>
   <!-- endbuild -->
   ```

   Since browsers will cache the resulting `main.js` file it will only have to be downloaded once.

Comment: so plugins like useref and usemin can not concat js from all .html files into the same main.js in the same location?

Comment: I don't think so, no. Each HTML file is processed on its own with no regard for what's defined in other HTML files.

Comment: my solution is -> gulp-replace-html which replaces only html without concating or copying files + gulp-concat with uglify and sourcemaps. Thanks for everything mate!

Comment: @riogrande  - could you please explain your solution, I have the same problem.